# ChangeNotifier changing but widget not updating with gestureDetector

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-change-notifier

I have this simple changeNotifierProvider

here it is

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CreatePetProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  String? _gender = 'Male';
  get gender => _gender;


  set changeGender(String gender){
    _gender = gender;
    // print(this.gender);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

here is in `main.dart`

```
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<CreatePetProvider>(
          create: (_) => CreatePetProvider(),
        )
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: AppTheme.lightTheme,
        home: const LoginScreen(),
        routes: routes,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's my widget which is not being updated

```
GestureDetector(onTap: () => _genderProvider.changeGender = 'Male', child: GenderButton(title: 'Male', selected: _genderProvider.gender == 'Male')),
GestureDetector(onTap: () => _genderProvider.changeGender = 'Female', child: GenderButton(title: 'Female', selected: _genderProvider.gender == 'Female'))
```

Those are simply two buttons which change their background when selected.

Here is the widget code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../../theme/app_theme.dart';

class GenderButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const GenderButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
    required this.selected,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  final bool selected;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 4),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: selected
              ? [AppTheme.gradient1, AppTheme.gradient2]
              : [Colors.white, Colors.white],
        ),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.25),
            spreadRadius: 0,
            blurRadius: 5,
            offset: const Offset(1, 1), // changes position of shadow
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: Text(
        title,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: selected ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          fontSize: 16,
          fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong every other provider in my app is working. I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're `notifyingListeners()` but what widget is listening for changes? Need wrap your listener with a `Consumer` widget.

Comment: But it would be helpful to see more of the code. Especially were you define the `_genderProvider`

Comment: My genderProvider is defined above Inside the build with `CreatePetProvider _genderProvider = Provider.of<CreatePetProvider>(context)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code is working fine. I am not facing any problem with this code. button is changing color, also ui gets selected gender perfectly.

check if you initialize provider correctly on ui in build function

```
 final _genderProvider = Provider.of<CreatePetProvider>(context);
```

Comment: I have initialized it like that. Maybe there's another problem with my provider package. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2):

you have to listen the changes, to update your widget.

`read` is update the value, but not update the UI **imidietly**, only updated when the widget marked as dirty widget.

`watch` when there's any changes, it rebuild the widget based on current value

```
 GestureDetector(
    onTap: () => context.read<Counter>().changeGender = 'Male',
    child: GenderButton(
        title: 'Male', selected: context.watch<Counter>().gender == 'Male')),
GestureDetector(
    onTap: () => context.read<Counter>().changeGender = 'Female',
    child: GenderButton(
        title: 'Female', selected: context.watch<Counter>().gender == 'Female'))
```

its not changed, because you have sepated class `GenderButton`. which is, the widget will not rebuild as long as its not marked as a dirty widget by flutter.
your gender value was updated, but the widget need to rebuild. then since its not dirty widget, flutter will keep to show old widget that show old value.

*sorry for my bad explanation, hope you got the point.